# Add static header to listFragment in onCreateView

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add a simple static header to my listview inside a listFragment? I want to create the header from an xml def and add it through inflation.

My onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View detailList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);
    View detailListHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_sales_header, null, false);
    container.addView(detailListHeader, 0);
    return detailList;
}
```

This creates the header, but it is not above the listview, rather the listview appears underneath the header, ie the header is overlaying the listview.

Any hints on the correct implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER EVER be adding views directly to the container in onCreateView().  Please read the documentation: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Also see the various sample code in the Fragment documentation, as well as the API demos: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html

There is nothing special about using a Fragment here.  Just build a view hierarchy containing a ListView like you normally would in an Activity or elsewhere.  You always need to return one View from onCreateView; this is the root of your hierarchy.

For example you could make the ListView and then use this to add a header to it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

Comment: I am not sure this answers the original question.  The question was about a static header.  I assume this means one outside of the view of the list.  addHeaderView adds an item in the list that will scroll with the list items.

Comment: This post does not answer the question, makes me wonder why OP accepted it

Answer (score 8):

Putting hackbod's description into code for you since his answer created more questions before the answers came. Sometimes I just want the fish. I don't always need to know how the net is made...

To start with, create a layout that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myListViewWithHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your onCreateView method you do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myListViewWithHeader, null);
    return view;
}
```

The header can now be populated by doing this:

```
// get the header view
TextView headerView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.header);
headerView.setText("Header text goes here");
```

Notice that my header is a TextView, but it can be replaced with another view if you like. In that case you will need to do a getView().findViewById(R.id.xxxxx) for each view inside the header you want to work with